# md-autocomplete Angular 1.x - bind data from parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a problem: how to bind properties from parent controller? When `md-selected-item` and `md-search-text` are properties from `AddTaskController` (i.e. `at.task.project`), autocomplete works fine (return matched elements). When I try to bind data from parent - `md-items | filter:edc.task.project` -  doesn't work properly (filter return all elements instead of matched items)
   http://plnkr.co/edit/ZCIU5gNwWfWdIOnz0ykb

```
<div ng-controller="EditTaskDialogController as edc">        
      <!-- autocomplete fields -->
          <div layout="row" ng-controller="AddTaskController as at">
            <!-- project autocomplete -->
            <div >
              <md-autocomplete required md-no-asterisk
                              md-input-name="project"
                              md-selected-item="edc.task.project"
                              md-search-text-change="at.searchProjectChange(edc.task.project)"
                              md-search-text="edc.task.project"
                              md-selected-item-change="at.selectedProjectChange(item)"
                              md-items="item in at.profile.projects | filter:edc.task.project"
                              md-item-text="item"
                              md-min-length="0"
                              md-input-minlength="0"
                              md-floating-label="Projekt...">
                          <md-item-template>
                              <span md-highlight-text="edc.task.project" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item}}</span>
                          </md-item-template>
                          <div ng-messages="editTaskForm.project.$error" role="alert">
                              <div ng-message="required">Pole nie może być puste.</div>
                          </div>
              </md-autocomplete>

            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a codepen/plunkr etc.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/3stDa5Y8Ou9iYD8ZNRdY here's Plunkr. First problem - filter doesn't work. Second - I have to clear input, unfocus input filed, then click on input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, you are just overwriting it with this: `md-search-text="edc.task.project"`. This is a reference and as soon as you clear the input field it will be set to undefined or empty. As a result your filter will not filter.

The second problem is because you set a `md-selected-item`. As soon as one is set, the input needs to be cleared before autocomplete will search again.